# Display Image Using AssetLibrary at Table view

Tags: ios

Currently i have 2 view Controllers, i select a photo from view controller,A and pass the image url to second view controller,B and use the url to retrieve the image selected from A.But problem is the image can be retrieved at viewDidLoad but cannot retrieve at table viewcellForRowAtIndexPath. I not sure what is the root cause can somebody help me?

//A.m

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// Initialize  View Controller B
B *b = [[B alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotosListViewController" bundle:nil];

// get the ref url
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
photoListViewController.test = imageURL;
NSLog(@"%@",imageURL);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoListViewController animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)organiseAttachement:(id)sender {

// Initialize  View Controller
B *b = [[PhotosListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
}
```

//B.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhotosListViewController : UITableViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *test;

@end
```

//B.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   NSLog(@"Image is THIS --- %@",test);

// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        self.galleryImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
    NSLog(@"[imageRep image] : %@", galleryImage);
};

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:test resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil]
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

   cell.imageView.image = self.galleryImage;
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: i would suggest to reload data inside the asset block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        self.galleryImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    }
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
    NSLog(@"[imageRep image] : %@", galleryImage);
};
```

with

```
// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        self.galleryImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //Reload the tableView.
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
    NSLog(@"[imageRep image] : %@", galleryImage);
};
```

## EDITED:

## A.m

```
@interface A ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) B *b;

@end

@implementation b

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

if(self.b)
{
   // Initialize  View Controller B
   self.b = [[B alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotosListViewController" bundle:nil];
}

// get the ref url
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
self.b.test = imageURL;
NSLog(@"%@",imageURL);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.b animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)organiseAttachement:(id)sender {

if(self.b == nil)
{
   // Initialize  View Controller
   self.b = [[PhotosListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.b animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: It is work now. The new problem now is when i did not select any image and go to view controller B to view the image, the image disappear,what is the root cause?

Comment: My view controller B code is already posted at above. I added the action of organiseAttachement at view controller A where user can click and go to the view controller B to organize the picture. But when click the button and push to the View controller B the photo in table view is gone.i not sure how to cache the image so that when push to the view controller the image still there.

Comment: make sure galleryImage is declared as @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *galleryImage;

Comment: yes, the galleryImage is declared as strong but image is disappear when go back to the view controller B from the view controller A.

Comment: In this case u need to store the instance of controller b as property in controller A. when the -organiseAttachement: method is called, every time a new instance is created without passing the image url. Hope you got the issue with ur code.

Comment: I tested to store the image appear in view controller B into an array Then pass back to view controller A so that organiseAttachement: method can  bring the image back to view controller B. But my problem is my array keep become empty once i choose another photo. i don't have any idea where goes wrong.

Comment: Check out the edited code above. Added some lines of code at the end. After the Edit text. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I did the same way as you but instead of that i declared as a variable after the @implementation and i get the expected result. Thanks.