# Display Photo Selected From Gallery into Table View

Tags: ios

My current problem is I cant manage to display more than one photo in table view controller B.
I try to used array to store the photo URL but my array only can store one URL when I selected the first photo. When i selected another photo my array will only replace the first url to the second and the first url is gone. Below is my code and this question was extending from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315472/display-image-using-assetlibrary-at-table-view/17315904?noredirect=1#comment25150686_17315904)

```
- (IBAction)organiseAttachement:(id)sender {

// Initialize  View Controller
PhotosListViewController *photoListViewController = [[PhotosListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotosListViewController" bundle:nil];
photoListViewController.test = imageURL;
collector = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
[self.collector addObject:imageURL];
NSLog(@"Collector in root %@",self.collector);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoListViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing array inside the method. So every time you click on the button, array get initialized. That's why ur first url lost. So keep array initialization outside this method.

```
collector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise the array like that:

```
collector = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i still get the same result which my first data in array been replace by second and first data is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array outside of this function. Initialize in viewDidLoad method. That is best for you.

```
collector = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```